# How to query the popular value of field as same as Kibana in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

When we use Kibana to query the application log, there is a panel shows TopN value for both keyword and text filed of document, as far as I known, text field is not recommended for aggregation, I wonder how Kibana query such aggregated data from Elasticsearch

[image]